# Hive jdbc - cannot select from my own table

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am logged as `pawel` user. In hive shell, I created a database `pawel_db` and a `test_table` in the database and filled it with one row data. This is what `ls` shows me:

```
[pawel@sandbox ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - pawel hdfs          0 2014-07-14 07:29 /apps/hive/warehouse/pawel_db.db
[...]
```

In the shell:

```
[pawel@sandbox ~]$ hive -e "use pawel_db; select * from test_table"

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 9.926 seconds
OK
777
Time taken: 5.243 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Everything seems to be fine. Problems start when I want to do some queries through jdbc:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://" + hiveHostAddress + ":" + hiveHostPort + "/pawel_db", "pawel", "");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("select * from test_table");
```

Throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied. Principal [name=pawel, type=USER] does not have following privileges on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=pawel_db.test_table] : [SELECT]
```

However, after executing in hive:

```
grant SELECT on table test_table to user pawel;
```

there is no exception. Do I really need to grant manually select privilege to the owner od the database? This doesn't seem to be logical.

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites
In order to use Hive authorization, there are two parameters that should be set in hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>enable or disable the hive client authorization</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.security.authorization.createtable.owner.grants</name>
  <value>ALL</value>
  <description>the privileges automatically granted to the owner whenever a table gets created. 
   An example like "select,drop" will grant select and drop privilege to the owner of the table</description>
</property>
```